# Environment variables on Windows in virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper-win

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv

On Linux machines, setting environment variables is a quick and easy command from the terminal. As a Python/Django developer working on multiple projects through virtual environments, the postactivate script of `virtualenvwrapper` is extremely useful for setting project-dependent environment variables. You access a virtualenv and you're environment variables are there, you deactive and poof they're gone.

In Windows I have both `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper-win`. Setting environment variables is done through the control panel, via the GUI, and is User-specific. Is there any way to have a similar setup to how it works on Linux? Perhaps through a Powershell script?

Answer (score 2):

With `conda` you can create these files: `/<path_to_env>/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.bat` which will be executes when the environment is activated. Put something like this in it:

```
set MYVAR=BLABLA
```

Similarly `/<path_to_env>/etc/conda/deactivate.d/env_vars.bat` gets executed when the env is deactivated.

```
set MYVAR=
```

(On Windows you delete env-vars by setting them to nothing.)

I've always used conda to manage my environments but as far as I know it's based on `virtualenv` so I don't see why something similar wouldn't also be possible with `virtualenvwrapper`.